# How to run mongodb bi connector as a kubernetes pod

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am able to run mongosqld locally and connect Tableau Desktop to my mongo database. The mongo database is running as pod in Amazon EKS. However when I create a pod for the mongodb bi connector and run the mongosqld command inside the pod, I am not able to connect Tableau Desktop to my mongo database pods. I do have a LoadBalancer for the mongodb bi connector and I am able to ping the loadbalancer. I am new to K8 and I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

This is the command I used:

```
mongosqld --mongo-uri "mongodb://internal-somerandommongouri.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017/?connect=direct" --mongo-username username --mongo-password password --auth --addr 0.0.0.0:3307
```

Below is my load balancer yaml config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  annotations: 
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
  name: mongodb-bi-connector
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: mongodb-bi-connector
spec: 
  ports: 
    - 
      port: 3307
      targetPort: 3307
  selector: 
    role: mongodb-bi-connector
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Here is the error message from Tableau Desktop:

```
An error occurred while communicating with MongoDB BI Connector.
```

The connection to the data source might have been lost.
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
Unable to connect to the MongoDB BI Connector server "internal-somerandommongouri.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

Comment: Hi Barsha, welcome to SO. Your question is highly unclear, as there are a lot of inconsistencies in your question. You mention mongo, but the error message says MySQL. It also is an internal LB, meaning only things inside the AWS VPC can access it -- do you have a VPN that places your machine inside the VPC?